# Reg Ex for the following data

Tags: regex, solr

I have an XML data field like this

```
<some info></some info><Some info2></some info2><description><lot of info></description><some more info></some more info><description><info></description>
```

I want a regex which will remove
 `<description>anything</description>`
for all the "description" tags. (there may be any arbitrary number of them)

I have to put this as a character pattern filter in Solr schema.

Comment: It would be helpful if you state the programming language you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get some people who will tell you either:

1. You can't parse XML with RegEx.
2. You should use a DOM library.

However, if all you want to do is remove things between `<description>` tags it should be as simple as search for `<description>.*?</description>` and replace with nothing.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion previously but what it does is removes everything till the last </description> tag, which I don't want. I want everything b/n every pair of description tag along with the description tag replaced with ""

Comment: What language are you using? In Perl the ? sets it to be a stingy match, which will prevent the problem you're describing. I do not believe all languages support this behaviour, so you may need another method of enabling stingy matching.

Comment: Solr is written in Java so the RegEx is also evaluated in it. Any idea how it is done in Java?